# How to fix corrupted partition without loss of data

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

Some time ago I accidentally `dd`ed ISO to my hard drive. After that I've reinstalled OS, but my Arch installation still recognize extended partition as ISO file and display it in Nautilus:

[image: Drives screenshot]

When I try to mount it I've got:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /run/media/hauleth/Linux Mint Debian 64-bit:
Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,
gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sda4"
"/run/media/hauleth/Linux Mint Debian 64-bit"' exited with non-zero
exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this once with a USB-Stick. The beginning of the hard drive or partition you `dd`ed the ISO to now has the beginning of the ISO as startblock. It may happen that this is not overwritten when creating a new filesystem or partition table. As to my knowledge this problem can't be resolved without loss of data. I solved it by overwriting the USB-Stick with zeros from /dev/zero and recreating the partition table.